# Do no change View WSO2-APIM from source

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I downloaded the source of ***product-apim*** from:\github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/release-2.1.0-rc5 and **Carbon-apimgt** from \github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/release-6.1.60-i840.

In the source of **Carbon-apimgt** I changed view Design API like the image below:

[image]

Step by step I changed:

1. Change name label in template.jag in ..\carbon-apimgt-release-6.1.60-i840\features\apimgt\org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.publisher.feature\src\main\resources\publisher\site\themes\wso2\templates\item-design\template.jag.
2. Use maven rebuild carbon-apimgt AND product-apim
3. In ....m2\repository\org\wso2\am\wso2am\2.1.0 extract file wso2am-2.1.0.zip
4. Start file wso2server.bat in folder BIN.

But: View Design API did not change.

Can you help me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to rebuild the product for any jaggery file changes. You can do this change directly to the product itself. Also, WSO2 API manager supports localization, You can check [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+Internationalization+and+Localization).

Also, tag should be 6.1.66 for carbon-apimgt repo.

Comment: Thank Abimaran Kugathasan.

Comment: Hi Abimaran Kugathasan

Answer (score 0):

i want modify function WSO2-API manage from source, such as: add Field value in form add API. 
Field in View now: Name, Context, Version,Visibility,Description,Tag. I want add Field: Provider(or Customer...) in View and save to Database.
Stream processing of source code??? and after add field i want deploy???